# With Bower, how do you include third party javascript in your build?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I just downloaded a javascript library, and I included it by copy pasting into index.html. Whenever I do a Bower serve or build, however, it is overwritten.

So far for my other javascript libraries it was easy by doing:

```
bower install --save LIBRARY_NAME
```

So for a library that cannot be installed by Bower, what should I do? How can I add it to my project so that it is picked up by the bower builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to `grunt` instead of `bower` for build or serve commands.

In your index.html you should see something like this :

```
<!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="scripts/custom/3dparty.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When you run a build or a serve, all the packages that you have loaded trough bower are added in the index.html into the tags `<!-- bower:js -->` and `<!-- endbower -->`, everything that you put here will be overidden.

You need to put the inclusion of your 3rd party script out of this to keep a reference on it  in your html, like I've done in the example.